# Source control confusion

Tags: git, git-repo

Im pretty new to android development although Ive been working on kernel for some time. 
The questions is: 
Ive made changes across modules in the kernel and from the top level directory of kernel, If I do git diff or git status, it shows all the changes that Ive made. This is fine.

Now, coming to Android, Ive made changes across multiple modules of android source and Ive lost track of all the changes that Ive made. I thought issuing git diff would fetch me all the changes that have gone into the android source. But unfortunately, when I did that, there is a message saying that it is not a git repository.

Now how can I find the changes that Ive made in android source? Should I have to go to each individual module like build/abi/bionic etc and do git diff? Any other way?

Comment: If it's not a git repo, then nothing is tracking your changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android project use [git-repo](http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) to manage all the git repositories.

So, to see all your diff in the Android tree just use [`repo diff`](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#diff).

Comment: That can't be right. The OP says "there is a message saying that it is not a git repository", and `repo` is just a wrapper around git. So if `git diff` didn't work, why would `repo diff`?

Comment: @Ajedi32 Because when you are in the Android tree, you can be out of any git tree (no `.git` directory), and in a repo tree (check the `.repo` directory at the root of the Android tree). E.g in the frameworks/ directory you CAN do `repo status` but you CAN NOT do `git status`. And in the frameworks/base directory you CAN do `repo status` AND `git status` because this is one of the several git repositories.